# Ripping subtitles from a TV box set on DVD

Tags: dvd, tv, subtitles

I've been scouring the 'net for info on how to do this, but the popular subtitle ripping tools only select the VOBs and then the largest title. I want to rip subtitles per episode, or in DVD terminology, by individual title. Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I should clarify that I want the subtitles to be OCR'ed into an srt file.

Comment: How have you structured the data, have you ripped by episode or just dumped the entire DVD?

Comment: I dumped the entire DVD, because I was planning on then encoding the episodes into MP4 files with HandBrake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you point [eac3to](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=125966) at the DVD directory root it should be able to rip the subs by episode. See the [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Eac3to/How_to_Use#Using_complete_disc_structure_as_inpu) for full info.

E.g, the below will extract (for title 3) the:

- chapters (track 2)
- video (track 3)
- audio (track 4)
- subs (track 5)

> eac3to "G:\Galapagos HD DVD 1080p VC-1 DD 2.0" 3) 2: galapagos.ep2.chapters.txt 3: galapagos.ep2.mkv 4: galapagos.ep2.ac3 5: galapagos.ep2.sup

You will need to do this for each title and you can then use [suprip](http://exar.ch/suprip/) to OCR the .sup file to .srt

---

**EDIT**

Alternatively, for .srt you could re-author the DVD using something like [DVD Shrink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_Shrink) which would allow you to split by episode. Your standard subrip would then read the new structure fine.

Comment: I'd prefer that the subtitles are OCR'ed into an srt file. Probably should have clarified that.

Comment: amended for OCR'ing the .sup file and an alternative method

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help:

http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/209730-How-do-I-convert-DVD-or-sub-idx-to-text-srt-subtitles

It contains info on where to locate subtitles, and how to rip them off a DVD.